# SDcard information linux

Tags: linux, command-line, sd-card, android-sdcard

I am trying to get **OEM** and other information from **SD** card which is on `/dev/sdc1`. Is there a command in linux to get the same like we do with **MMC**. Ex: `/sys/block/mmcblk0/device/cid` to get *cid*, `/sys/block/mmcblk0/device/oemid` to get the *oemid*?

I would appreciate if you could let me know how to do get this programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

If it's appearing in the scsi (/dev/sdX) subsystem, that means there is some piece of hardware between you and the card, almost certainly a controller that implements the usb storage protocol.  I don't think there's a standard mechanism to expose SD/MMC specific information across that, though it's possible your hardware has something specific.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Yes, there is an adaptor that sits between the hardware and the SDCard.